# How come the last 3 rows of cells in my table are not perfectly lined up with the 1st row in my HTML table?

Tags: html, css, html-table, row

Here is a [link my example of the misaligned table rows](http://jsbin.com/uhoqo4/2/edit)

Click preview in the upper top left corner of the JS Bin menu bar to see this example in the works. You can see the top 2 borders of the table cells with **Email** and an **input** field in them are a bit lower than the top 2 borders of the 2 table cells to the left of them (**Username** and an **input** field).

Why is this happening?

Also I am finding I have to write `rowspan="4"` for `<th>` and `<td>` elements in the second  element to make them span the 3 rows beside it. Why do I have to do that? It makes no sense if there are only 3 rows I have to clear. It's as if there is a mysterious hidden row somewhere.

UPDATE with example answer:

[I implemented the answer in this example.](http://jsbin.com/uhoqo4/3/edit) As you can see, there is perfect alignment between all table cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

right... easy peasy...

basically, the second row needs to have 4 cells in it, the username and input cells AND the email and input cells...

the username and input cells need to have `rowspan="3"` and then the NEXT two rows need to be password and new password with their input fields.

code:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table border="1">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="4" rowspan="1">
            <h3>Profile Settings</h3>
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th rowspan="3">
            <label for="">USERNAME:</label>
          </th>
          <td rowspan="3">  
            <input type="text">
          </td>
          <th>
            <label for="">Email:</label>
          </th>
          <td>  
            <input type="text">
          </td>  
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>
            <label for="">Password:</label>
          </th>
          <td>  
            <input type="password">
          </td>  
        </tr>  
        <tr>
          <th>
            <label for="">New Password:</label>
          </th>
          <td>  
            <input type="password">
          </td>  
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="4">  
            <input type="button" value="save">
          </td>  
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: say, that was tricky! very nice :) you have enlightened me and I thank you deeply.

Answer (score 0):

Your first row is has 1 td with a colspan of 4, but your second row is 2 td's both with a normal colspan?

Your mark up is flawed, fix this first.

What is the end result supposed to look like?
The way it looks now?

Comment: its supposed to look exactly as it does now but with the 3rd <tr> not being like 3 pixels lower than the 2nd <tr>